# JFrame gets decorated with Windows borders, even the Look&Feel is set otherwise

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

Good day everyone.

First of all: check this image.
[image]

Please note that in the first of the 3 frames, the button is styled with Metal Look and Feel, but the frame is Windows styled. The other 2 frames are "OK" in the sence that the button LAF matches the frame LAF.

The code for all of these (same order as the images):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("button"));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
            frame.setSize(100, 100); 

            frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("button"));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // 0 => "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"
                // 3 => the Windows Look and Feel
                String name = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()[3].getClassName();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(name);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("button"));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    });
}
```

Now what bothers me is that I have never been forced to use the lines `frame.setUndecorated(true); frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);`, as setting the Look and Feel just worked with the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` method. Normally, the JFrame itself would get styled too, but this seems not longer the case as I get a Windows styled frame (1st image, 1 code snippet).

Why is this? Is this new in Java 7? This seems really weird.

Normally, without touching code that involves Look and Feel, the program should start with the Metal Look and Feel, as this is the standard Java Look and Feel. So why does the first program start with a Windows frame?

Answer (score 6):

Add this line in your main method before you init the JFrame

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

I noticed the same thing a while ago when I started using substance but that line is all it took to fix it.

> As the preceding code snippet implies, you must invoke the setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated method before creating the frame whose decorations you wish to affect. The value you set with setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated is used for all subsequently created JFrames. You can switch back to using window system decorations by invoking JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(false). Some look and feels might not support window decorations; in this case, the window system decorations are used.

That's from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) in reference to that line of code.

This is a feature of Java, by default JFrame Window borders will not be decorated, but using the mentioned function allows the set look and feel to decorate the Window. This feature was implemented in 1.4 from what I can tell.

Edit:

Also, if you want to apply your custom look and feel to JDialog window borders, you can use the same static method on the JDialog class in the same place you called it on JFrame:

```
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

Comment: While this works and I discovered this too, this is not a real answer to my question, because I have never used this particular line of code before and setting the Look and Feel has always worked for me with the code from example #3. I must say I have been using Substance, but the examples in the question post are made within a fresh project without any libraries. If the issue is explained by some Java SDK changes or possibly a new Java bug, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Also, if you are curious why your middle solution worked you can view [this method doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you hane not set the `swing.defaultlaf` system environment variable, but maybe you could check if your `swing.properties` is present and if it contains an entry `swing.defaultlaf`. This could be the reason, see below for how the UIManager chooses L&F.

I have the file present on my MacBook, obviously, as Apple wants the Apple L&F to be the default. But I have not checked a Windows machine yet..

Here's an excerpt from the Java 7 documentation which has been pretty much unchanged since Java 1.4. [Java 1.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html), [Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html), [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html), [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html):

#### Default look and feel

The class used for the default look and feel is chosen in the following
 manner:

1. If the system property `swing.defaultlaf` is
          `non-null`, use its value as the default look and feel class
          name.

   If the `Properties` file `swing.properties`
          exists and contains the key `swing.defaultlaf`,
          use its value as the default look and feel class name. The location
          that is checked for `swing.properties` may vary depending
          upon the implementation of the Java platform. In Sun's implementation
          the location is `${java.home}/lib/swing.properties`.
          Refer to the release notes of the implementation being used for
          further details.

   Otherwise use the cross platform look and feel.